# Java - iterate through 3 variables of differing array lengths

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I am trying to iterate through the following pseudo-code set up, and I seem to be stuck using for loops and case distinctions only. Is there a simple way to go through these?

Edit: To be more clear, I have two 2-dimensional double arrays of coordinates given such that I have PunkteX[i][m] and PunkteY[i][m]. These two arrays will always be of the same length, but the integers i and m are variable. I would like to loop through them, for in order to combine them into a new 2-dimensional array of type Point2D[p]. The length of the Point2D array will be determined by i and m.

```
int i = punkteX.length; // same as punkteY.length;
int m = punkteX[0].length;  // same as punkteY[0].length;
Point2D[] array = new Point2D[i*m];

array[0] = (punkteX[0][m], punkteY[0][m]);
array[1] = (punkteX[1][m], punkteY[1][m]);    
array[2] = (punkteX[2][m], punkteY[2][m]);
.
.
array[i-1] = (punkteX[i-1][m], punkteY[i-1][m]);
array[i]   = (punkteX[i][m], punkteY[i][m]);
array[i+1] = (punkteX[0][m-1], punkteY[0][m-1]);
array[i+2] = (punkteX[1][m-1], punkteY[1][m-1]);
array[i+3] = (punkteX[2][m-1], punkteY[2][m-1]);
.
.
array[p-1] = (punkteX[i-1][0], punkteY[i-1][0]);
array[p] = (punkteX[i][0], punkteY[i][0]);
```

My attempt, for the sake of completeness, which only seems to work for i = 3 is the following:

```
    for (int p = 0; p < array.length; ++p) {
        for (int m = 0; m < mtimes; ++m) { // mtimes = column length of PointX and PointY Arrays
        Point2D[] interimarray = new Point2D[n]; // Global var n = i
        for (int i = 0; i < interimarray.length; ++i) {
            p = (p+i); 
            if (i == (interimarray.length-1)) { p -= 1; }
            if (p < (array.length)) {
                array[p] = new Point2D(xArray[i][(mtimes-m-1)], yArray[i][(mtimes-m-1)]);}
            if ((p!= 0) && (i==(n-1))) { p += 1; }}}}
```

Comment: You'd be better explaining what you're trying to achieve in this pseudocode - it's not obvious what you're trying to do.

Comment: Yeah this is very confusing. I have no idea what you're trying to do here. Do you have a data structure and you're trying to navigate through it? Or are you trying to create a data structure AND navigate through it?

Comment: Also should add, it's at a risk of being closed because of the fact of how unclear it is.

Comment: So you want to generate 2D arrays of variable number of rows and columns or something?

Comment: I have added some specification, does the question make a little more sense now?

Comment: It helps a bit. What do mean by "combine" them? How can you combine them if they are of different lengths?

Comment: How do you want to combine the two sets of coordinates?

Comment: They can be combined, because PunkteX and PunkteY will always have the same shape. I just need to fetch the right indices so that they give the above given structure. So, I have two 2-dimensional arrays given and I want to combine them into a new 2-dimensional array (of type Point2D).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still very confusing to me, but this will generate the configuration you're looking for. The p index always increases with each iteration through an i array, so you can just do p++ in that loop. Other than that it's just a nested for loop.

```
int p = 0;
for(int m = mArray.length - 1; m >= 0; m--) {
    for(int i = 0; i < iArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("p = " + p + ", i = " + i + ", m = " + m);
        p++;
    }
}
```

If you are struggling with how to store your new data structure, what you probably want to use is a wrapper class. The wrapper class will hold both of the double coordinate arrays from punkteX and punkteY. This code will take your two arrays, loop through them, and store them in point2DArray, which is of type Point2D, our wrapper class. I have also included an example wrapper class so you see how the data is stored.

```
int mArrayLength = punkteX[0].length;
int iArrayLength = punkteX.length;
Point2D[] point2DArray = new Point2D[mArrayLength];
int p = 0;
for(int m = 0; m < mArrayLength; m++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < iArrayLength; i++) {
        point2DArray[p] = new Point2D(punkteX[i][m], punkteY[i][m]);
        p++;
    }
}

public class Point2D {
    private double[] punkteX;
    private double[] punkteY;

    public Point2D(double[] punkteX, double[] punkteY) {
        this.punkteX = punkteX;
        this.punkteY = punkteY;
    }

    public double[] getPunkteX() {
        return punkteX;
    }

    public double[] getPunkteY() {
        return punkteY;
    }
}
```

Then if you wanted to get out a specific punkteX and punkteY (say when p = 0), you'd use this on your new data structure:

```
double[] punkteXValue = point2DArray[0].getPunkteX();
double[] punkteYValue = point2DArray[0].getPunkteY();
```

Aside: Don't use caps at the front of variable names in Java, it makes them look like class names. Good code conventions will make people much more likely to help you since it will be easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for providing a working example and especially for the additional input! I will still have to look at and potentially incorporate all ideas in some way, but that is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That's my Solution:

```
public class Test {

    private final static int P = 20;
    private final static int M = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int m = 5;
        int i = 0;

        for (int p=0; p < P; p++)
        {
            if (p % M == 0)
            {
                m--;
                i = 0;
            }
            System.out.println ("p = " + p +" i = " + i  +" m = " + m );
            i++;

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
int m = mtimes;
int p = 0;
while (m >= 0) {
    int itimes = ...; //row length;
    for (int i = 0; i < itimes; i++) {
        // 
        p++;
    }

    m--;
}
```